# Excel VBA - Code is converting a decimal to integer when read from cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have never noticed this before and I'm not sure what it causing it. I have a series of decimal values in column A:

[image]

...and a piece of code that is supposed to read those values:

```
currentValue = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Values").Cells(n, 1))
```

`currentValue` is listed as a 'Long' in the variable explorer, but when the code reaches that line it stores the values read from the Values worksheet rounded to the nearest integer. Any ideas why? It has nothing to do with the first value being '0', I checked that!

Comment: `Dim CurrentValue As Double`.

Comment: Add on to VBasic2008. Integer/Long can only store whole numbers. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) for the different data types.

Comment: Please always post complete sub or function blocks.

Comment: Thanks! It was the Dim Long that was the problem. I hadn't used VBA in a while and for some reason I was convinced it was floating point. The code works with Double. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

I haven't the slightest idea why it's converting the long to an Int; an undefined variant should keep the format of its contents.

Can you step through your code and see what the value in CurrentValue is after pulling in the val from your worksheet? Like... right after that line in your question is, debug.Print CurrentValues to see what it contains. My best guess is that that wherever you eventually paste CurrentValues into is formatted to be Int or rounded to the nearest whole number.

You could either declare CurrentValue as a Double in early binding or convert the cell value to decimal using the CDec function. See my code's results below:

```
Public Function TestingThis()
    Dim ws     As Worksheet
    Dim dblVal As Double
    
    Set ws = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    For i = 2 To 8
        currentValue = ws.Cells(i, 1) 'How you have it in yor example code
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = currentValue
        
        dblVal = ws.Cells(i, 1) 'Using a early binding Double Var to retain decimal format
        ws.Cells(i, 3) = dblVal
        
        ws.Cells(i, 4) = CDec(ws.Cells(i, 1)) 'Using the CDec Function to retain decimal format
    Next i
    
End Function
```

[image: Image showing different conversion techniques in Excel and VBA]

Comment: Although it's not specified in the question - It appears `currentValue` is delcated as `Long` *`currentValue` is listed as a 'Long' in the variable explorer*. In VBA both `Integer` and `Long` are not floating point data types, `Double` or `Decimal` are - see [MS Documentation for Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary).

Comment: You say: *I haven't the slightest idea why it's converting the long to an Int.* Then why answer and do it wrong? Instead you should have requested OP to improve their question. `currentvalue` is declared as `Long`.

Comment: Thanks! It was the Dim Long that was the problem. I hadn't used VBA in a while and for some reason I was convinced it was floating point. The code works with Double. Cheers!

Comment: @TomBrunberg Well excuse me for trying to help... and providing different solutions other than the common rudeness I see on this site (Like your response) so frequently.